# Probability theory for random string generator

Tags: math, theory

I would like to understand the "Probability theory" and how it works.

Imagine we have 2 variables (x,y)
If x contains the alphabet letters a-z and y contains the numbers 0-9

From merging them, how many strings can we get?

Another Example is,

```
     function generate($l=10){ 
$str = ""; for ($x=0;$x<$l;$x++)
    $str .= substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 1); 
    return $str; }
```

Again, from merging them, how many strings can we get?

Thanks!

Comment: you forgot to add `I've searched for hours but cannot find a thing about "Probability theory" on the net`.

Comment: If you were to write a loop to produce all possible combinations, how many rows would it output?

Comment: Please define "merging them."

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the number of combinations that a String of length 1-10 can be, with the character set a-z, 0-9. That means there are 36 possible characters to choose from.

The total number of combinations is equal to the sum of combinations for each String length.

For a String of length 1, there are 36 possibilities (a, b, ..., z, 0, 1, ..., 9).

For a String of length 2, there are 36^2 possibilities (aa, ab, ..., az, a0, ..., a9, ba, ..., 99)

For a String of length 3, there are 36^3 possibilities, you are seeing the pattern.

At every length, there are 36^(length of the String). So, the total number of combinations is the sum of 36^1, 36^2, ..., 36^10.

Comment: But what about having ab1 ab2 ab3 abc1 abcdef1 abcdef2 etc? This is what I mean by total outcome strings I can get

Comment: @hobaa You are not being clear in the slightest. What is your exact problem? _How long can the String be_, _what letters are allowed (a-z, A-Z?)_?

Comment: String can be 10 and (a-zA-z-0-9) are allowed

Comment: @hobaa "String can be 10" - why didn't you state this in the original question? Now you tell us?

Comment: @hobaa can the string length be 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9, or 10?

Comment: @hobaa abc3456789 allowed?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't so clear so let me clarify it.
Imagine we have 2 numbers (0,1) and 2 letters (a,b), the possible outcome strings can be
(0a,0b,0aa,0bb,0ab,0bb,1a,1b,00,01,11,aa,bb,ab,ba) and so on.
So from merging 0-10/a-z/A-Z How many possible outcome strings can we get?

And yes for the question you asked!

Comment: @hobaa for your above example, are 0, 1, a, and b also possible outcome strings?